# How can I decode Microsoft Graph API MessageConversationId

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have multiple messages that I obtained through the MS Graph API and I want to group them by conversation. All the messages from the conversation got the same MessageConversationId for the same user, but I want to group them across multiple O365 users. The same conversation between  multiple users has different id's, but I noticed that the last 26 characters are the same. The MessageConversationId looks like an encoded string, maybe there is data inside that would allow me to match across different users. How can I decode it?

Can I request immutable MessageConversationIds?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to work with the PidTagConversationId  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxomsg/f8e4a5fa-cb73-4eca-b174-72e1fda821a6 and PidTagConversationIndex  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxomsg/9e994fbb-b839-495f-84e3-2c8c02c7dd9b. You can also work with the InReplyTo and Referances Mime headers